# Swiftmailer adds line breaks to text/plain template

Tags: php, swiftmailer, fluid

I'm using a contract.txt as template for a text/plain email:

```
Eine Bestellung wurde gesendet:

Vertragspartner: {contract.formData.customer}
Zweiter Vertragspartner: {contract.formData.secondCustomer}

Anschrift:
{contract.formData.address}
{contract.formData.zipCity}

...
```

This is rendered by a `standaloneView`, which generates the following String:

```
Eine Bestellung wurde gesendet:

Vertragspartner: Herr Max Mustermann (11.11.1991)
Zweiter Vertragspartner: Nein

Anschrift:
Holzweg 13 Holzweg 13
90909 Bielefeld

...
```

This is the expected result.
However, when I call `setBody($message, 'text/plain');` swiftmailer inserts new line breaks and `=` to the message:

```
Eine Bestellung wurde gesendet:

Vertragspartner: Herr Max Mustermann (=
11.11.1991)
Zweiter Vertragspartner: Nein

Anschrift:
Holzweg 13 Ho=
lzweg 13
90909 Bielefeld

...
```

---

It looks like swiftmailer tries to enforce the 76 characters line limit, without considering the existing line breaks, which are still there, after.
Answers to similar questions however state that this problem was fixed a long time ago.

Here is the code I use to create the email with SwiftMailer 5.4.2 in a TYPO3 Neos plugin:

```
$standaloneView = new StandaloneView();
$standaloneView->setTemplatePathAndFilename('resource://[...]/Contract.txt');
$standaloneView->assign('contract', $contract);
$message = $standaloneView->render();

$mail = new Message();
$mail->setFrom([$formData['email'] => $formData['lastname']])
  ->setTo([
    $this->request->getInternalArgument('__mailRecipientAddress') => $this->request->getInternalArgument('__mailRecipientName')
  ])
  ->setSubject($this->request->getInternalArgument('__mailSubject'))
  ->setBody($message, 'text/plain');
```

What has to be done in order to make SwiftMailer recognize my existing linebreaks?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to *prevent* this error, but it does not *solve* it.

The standaloneView renders the template using `LF (\n)` for newlines, while `setBody()` tries to standardize all newlines to `CRLF (\r\n)`, but apparently fails.

So I just did this myself using a `str_replace()`. The message is now defined by

```
$message = str_replace("\n", "\r\n", $standaloneView->render());
```

instead of `$message = $standaloneView->render();`

I'm pretty sure, there's a better way to solve the problem, however this fixed my emails, so I'm leaving it here.